# Exam Question in Analysis

Tags: real-analysis

this is the third part of an exam question.  I needed a little help starting it.  Thanks in advance.

Let $f$ be integrable on a measure space $(X, \mu)$ with $\mu(X) = 1$.  Show that $\displaystyle ||f||_p \rightarrow \exp \left(\int_X\log |f|d\mu \right)$ as $p \rightarrow 0.$

Hint: Apply a convergence theorem to $|f| - 1 - \dfrac{|f|^p - 1}{p}$.

Comment: See: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/115428/about-a-probability-measure/115460#115460

Comment: Answered in http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/282271/scaled-lp-norm-and-geometric-mean/282311#282311

Comment: I understand this proof, but how would you go about proving the statement incorporating the above hint?

Answer (score 1):

In order to use the hint, consider $\{p_n\}$ a sequence which converges to $0$ and define 
$$f_n(x):=|f(x)|-1-\frac{|f|^{p_n}-1}{p_n}.$$
Look at the pointwise convergence of $\{f_n\}$, then try to find a dominating integrable function.