# The $p \rightarrow 0$ limit of $p-$norms of random variables

Tags: probability

If $X$ is a random variable then is it true that,

$$\liminf_{p \rightarrow 0}\ \lVert X \rVert_ p  = \exp [ \mathbb{E} [ \log \lvert X \rvert]]\quad  ?$$

---

I am unable to see this to be true even for finite random variables. Like if $X$ takes two values say $x_1$ and $x_2$ with probabilities $p_1 \in [0,1]$ and $1-p_1$ respectively then the above claim is saying that,

$\liminf _{p \rightarrow 0} (p_1 x_1 ^p + (1-p_1)x_2^p )^\frac{1}{p} = x_1^{p_1} x_2^{1-p_1} $

I don't know why the above must be true!

Answer (score 0):

[From here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/115428/limit-of-lp-norm-when-p-to0) you get $$\displaystyle\lim_{p\to 0} \left[ \int_{\Omega}|X(\omega)|^p\mu (d\omega ) \right]^{\frac{1}{p}}=\exp \left[ \int_{\Omega}\log|X(\omega )| \mu (d\omega)  \right],$$ what can be rewritten  as $$\liminf_{p \rightarrow 0}\ \lVert X \rVert_ p  = \exp [ \mathbb{E} [ \log \lvert X \rvert]]\quad  $$

Comment: This should be a duplicate notice, or a comment at best, not an answer.