# Applying Jensen's inequality to Real and Complex Analysis Exercise 3.5

Tags: analysis

I'm attempting Rudin Real and Complex Analysis 3.5 (a) and trying to apply Jensen's Inequality.

In the solution given [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/115428/limit-of-lp-norm-when-p-to0/115460#115460), I wasn't sure why Jensen's inequality implies that $g(p):=\frac 1p\log\int_{\Omega}|f|^pd\mu-\int_{\Omega}\log|f|d\mu \ge 0$.
Since by the vanilla version of Jensen's inequality (concave), 
we should have $\log\int_{\Omega}|f|d\mu-\int_{\Omega}\log|f|d\mu \ge 0$.

I'm curious where the $\frac 1p$ and the $p$-power in the integrand come from. Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

\begin{align*}
\int\log|f|d\mu&=\int\dfrac{1}{p}\log|f|^{p}d\mu\\
&=\dfrac{1}{p}\int\log|f|^{p}d\mu\\
&\leq\dfrac{1}{p}\log\int|f|^{p}d\mu.
\end{align*}