# Proof Verification: $\lim_{p\to 0} \|f\|_p = \exp\left\{\int_X \log |f|\ d\mu \right\}$ (Big Rudin's Ex $3.5$)

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, solution-verification

This appears as Ex. $3.5(d)$ in Rudin's *Real and Complex Analysis*.

> Suppose $f:X\to\mathbb C$ is a measurable function on $X$, $\mu$ is a positive measure on $X$, and $\mu(X) = 1$. Assume that $\|f\|_r < \infty$ for some $r >0$, and prove that $$\lim_{p\to 0} \|f\|_p = \exp\left\{\int_X \log |f|\ d\mu \right\}$$ if $\exp\{-\infty\}$ is defined to be $0$.

I saw a related proof [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/282271/scaled-lp-norm-and-geometric-mean), and I write this post to confirm the correctness of my proof which fills in all details and removes apparently unnecessary assumptions from the linked answer.

**My work:** For $0 < p < \infty$, we have $$\tag{1}\int_X \log|f|\ d\mu \le \log\|f\|_p$$ using Jensen's inequality (and that $\log$ is a concave function).

From Q5(a) of Rudin, we have $$\tag{2} 0 < r < s \le \infty \implies \|f\|_r \le \|f\|_s$$

From the graph of $x \mapsto \frac{a^x - 1}{x}$, $\log a \le \frac{a^x - 1}{x}$ for $x > 0$. Put $a = \left(\int_X |f|^{1/n} \ d\mu\right)^{n}$ to get $$\tag{3} \log \|f\|_{1/n} \le \int_X \frac{|f|^{1/n} - 1}{1/n}\ d\mu$$
Let $A = \{x: |f(x)| \ge 1\}$ and $B = \{x: |f(x)| < 1\}$.
$$\int_X \frac{|f|^{1/n} - 1}{1/n}\ d\mu = \int_A \frac{|f|^{1/n} - 1}{1/n}\ d\mu + \int_B \frac{|f|^{1/n} - 1}{1/n}\ d\mu$$
Recall that $\|f\|_r < \infty$ for some $r > 0$. For $a >0$, $x \mapsto \frac{a^x - 1}{x}$ is an  increasing function in $x$. $\frac{|f|^{1/n} - 1}{1/n}$ is dominated by $\frac{|f|^{r} - 1}{r}$ for large enough $N$, where the latter is integrable. On $B$, $\frac{|f|^{1/n} - 1}{1/n} < 0$, so $\frac{1 - |f|^{1/n}}{1/n} > 0$. In fact, on $B$, as $n\to\infty$, $\frac{1 - |f|^{1/n}}{1/n}\nearrow -\log|f|$ pointwise. We can apply MCT on $B$, and the DCT on $A$, to get
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_X \frac{|f|^{1/n} - 1}{1/n}\ d\mu = \lim_{n\to\infty} \int_A \frac{|f|^{1/n} - 1}{1/n}\ d\mu - \lim_{n\to\infty}\int_B \frac{1 - |f|^{1/n}}{1/n}\ d\mu\\
= \int_A \log|f|\ d\mu + \int_B \log|f|\ d\mu= \int_X \log|f|\ d\mu$$

Due to inequality (2), and inequality (1), $\lim_{p\to 0} \log \|f\|_p$ exists.

In inequality (3), take limits as $n\to\infty$ to get $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\log\|f\|_{1/n} \le \int_X \log|f|\ d\mu$$
$$\lim_{p\to 0}\log\|f\|_{p} \le \int_X \log|f|\ d\mu \tag{4}$$
Taking $p\to 0$ in inequality (1), we have $$\lim_{p\to 0}\log\|f\|_{p} \ge \int_X \log|f|\ d\mu \tag{5}$$
$$\implies \lim_{p\to 0}\log\|f\|_{p} = \int_X \log|f|\ d\mu \tag{6}$$
Since $\log$ is continuous, $$\lim_{p\to 0} \|f\|_p = \exp\left\{\int_X \log |f|\ d\mu \right\}$$

---

Thank you! Please help fill in the gaps if any, and in particular, check if the MCT/DCT part is good.

Comment: Your arguments seem  correct. Convexity of the function $p\mapsto a^p$ for $p>0$ ($a>0$) is the key to get monotonicity. Since $(X,\mu)$ is a probability space, you can actually do without splitting the integral by using Jensen's inequality. [Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3998110/121671) is a solution along the line of your reasoning but without splitting.

Comment: Thank you very much, Oliver!

Comment: @epilon-emperor: your welcome. By the way, I noticed, to my chagrin, that people refer to Rudin's Principle's of Mathematica analysis as "baby Rudin", and his Real and Complex Analysis as "Papa Rudin". I disagree with the labeling since Rudin has also another rather famous text book: Functional Analysis. So in all justice, I would use the labeling "baby Rudin", "young Rudin" and "papa Rudin" respectively, or something like that.  He also has a couple of rather well known specialize books: "Fourier Analysis on Groups" and "Function Theory in the unit ball". Those should be "grandpa Rudin"

Comment: I didn't know about so many of the books you mentioned - thanks a lot! I was under the impression that Chapters 3-8 of Rudin's *Real and Complex Analysis* are Functional Analysis - did not know there is a separate book!

Comment: Indeed,  he wrote Functional Analysis in the early 70's and there are two editions to it. He wrote Principles in 63 and his Fourier analysis on groups  in 1962.