# Does convergence in $L^{\log}$ implies convergence in probability?

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

We say that a sequence of random variables $X_n$ converges in $L^{\log}$ to $X$ if
$$
\exp\left(\mathbb{E}\left[\log\left|X_n-X\right|\right]\right) \to 0\quad\text{as}\quad n\to\infty.
$$
Is it true that, if $X_n$ converges in $L^{\log}$, then $X_n$ also converges in probability?
I know how to show that this is true if $X_n$ converges in $L^p$ for $1<p<\infty$, but I couldn't figure out how to prove or disprove this when $p\searrow 0$ which corresponds to the notion of convergence in $L^{\log}$ as we can see in this [proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/115428/limit-of-lp-norm-when-p-to0).
How should I approach this?

Comment: $L_0$ has other metrics that coincide with convergence of probability. For example $\|f\|_0=\inf\{\varepsilon>0: P[|f|>\varepsilon]\leq \varepsilon\}$ or $g(X)=E[|X|\wedge1]$. The distances being $d(fog):=\|f-g\|_0$ and $\rho(f, g)=E[|f-g|\wedge1]$.

Comment: Notice also that convergence in probability also follows from convergence in $L_p$ for $0<p<1$. However, $\|f\|_p$ does not induce a metric in such $L_p$ spaces, $\|f\|^p_p$ does. Although $\|f\|_p\xrightarrow{p\rightarrow0+}\exp(E[\log(|f|)]$ for any $f\in \bigcap_{r>0}L_r(\mathbb{P})$, the distance properties of $\|f\|^{\min(1,p)}_p$ are not preserved by the limit.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the space $L^0$. Is it interpreted as the space of $f$ with $\exp(\mathbb{E}[\log |f|])<\infty$? Does it coincide with $\bigcap_{r>0} L^r(\mathbb{P})$?

Comment: The space $L_0$ is the set of almost surely finite measurable functions (it contains alll $L_p$'s in particular. It just so happens that in this space, there is a distance that  gives convergence in probability. Notice that at the other end of the spectrum one has $\bigcap_{r>0}L_p(\mathbb{P}$, where your limit operates. What I am saying is that the limit $\exp(E[\log(|f|)])$ is not closed to be a distance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Counter-example:  Let $X_n$ take the values $n$ and $\frac 1 {n^{2}}$ with probability $\frac 1 2$ each. Let $X=0$.  Then the hypothesis holds but $P(|X_n-X| >\epsilon) \to \frac 1  2$.