# Prove that $ \lim_{p\rightarrow 0^+}(\frac{1}{|E|}\int_E f^p)^{\frac{1}{p}}=\exp(\frac{1}{|E|}\int_E \log f) $

Tags: real-analysis, integration, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

I ask this question two days ago, but no one answer or comment. Thus, I reedit my question and edit more about mine thought. Hope someone can help me prove that. Here the question:

Let $E$ be a measurable set in $\mathbb{R^n}$ with $|E| <\infty$. Suppose that $f > 0$ a.e. in $E$ and $f, \log f \in L^1(E)$. Prove that
$$
\lim_{p\rightarrow 0^+}\left(\frac{1}{|E|}\int_E f^p\right)^{\frac{1}{p}}=\exp\left(\frac{1}{|E|}\int_E \log f\right)
$$

First, I think to show that $$\frac{f^p-1}{p} \rightarrow \log f$$
Whlie I don't know what should I do next that can help to get the result can I take $\frac{1}{p}$ down by $\log$? or first step I think should be change. I think to use LDCT, but I can't find $\phi$ to control $f^p.$

---

Another question is let $f$ be measurable, nonnegative, and finite a.e. in a set $E$. Prove that for any nonnegative constant $c$,
$$\int_E e^{cf(x)}dx=|E|+c\int_0^\infty e^{c\alpha}\omega_f(\alpha)d(\alpha)$$

I think that deduce that $e^{cf} \in L(E)$ if $|E| < \infty$ and there exist constants $C_1$  and $c_1$ such that $c_1>c$ and $\omega_f(\alpha) \leq C_1e^{-c_1\alpha}$ for all $\alpha>0$. I try to use $$\int_E \phi(f)=-\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\phi(\alpha)d\omega(\alpha)$$
Thus,
$$\int_E e^{cf}=-\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{c\alpha} d\omega(\alpha)=-\int_{-\infty}^{0}e^{c\alpha} d\omega(\alpha)-\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{c\alpha} d\omega(\alpha)$$
What can I do next to get the result?

How can I prove this two questions?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Limit of $L^p$ norm when $p\to0$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/115428/limit-of-lp-norm-when-p-to0)

Comment: The two questions are not related. I suggest you post two different questions. Your first question has been already answered before in MSE (hence the link I put in my comment). The second can be solved as an excessive on Fubini's theorem.

Comment: Yes, it includes two different question. For second question I write a little above but stuck what to do next. I haven't learn Fubini's theorem, so I think it can do it without it.Do you have some idea about mine prove above of second question.

Answer (score 1):

The first question has already been answered in MSE, see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/115428/121671) for example.

---

As for the second question, assuming that $f\geq0$ and $\mu(E) <\infty$, one can use Fubini's theorem to get

\begin{align}
\int_Ee^{cf}d\mu&=\int_E\big(e^{cf}-1+1\big)d\mu=\mu(E)+\int_E(e^{cf}-1)\,d\mu\\
&=\mu(E)+ c \int_E\Big(\int^f_0 e^{ct}\,dt\Big)\,d\mu\\
&\stackrel{Fubini}{=}\mu(E)+ c\int^\infty_0\Big(\int_E e^{ct}\mathbb{1}_{\{f >t\}}\,d\mu\Big)\,dt\\
&=\mu(E)+ c\int^\infty_0e^{ct}\mu(f>t)\,dt
\end{align}

***Comment:***

There are some treatments of integration theory in which the Lebegue integral of a measurable nonnegative function $f$ is defined as
$$\int_E f\,d\mu:=\int^\infty_0\mu(x\in E: f(x)>t)\,dt$$
where the integral in the right-hand-side is taken in the sense of improper Riemann integral. See *Lieb, E. and Loss, M., Analysis, AMS, 2001* for example. In such case, an alternative solution can be obtained along the following lines:

\begin{align}
\int_E e^{cf}\,d\mu&=\int^\infty_0\mu(e^{cf}>t)\,dt=\int^\infty_0\mu(f>\frac1c\log t)\,dt\\
&\stackrel{u=\frac1c\log t}{=}c\int^\infty_{-\infty}\mu(f>u)e^{cu}\,du\\
&=c\int^0_{-\infty}\mu(f>u)e^{cu}\,du+ c\int^\infty_0\mu(f>u)e^{cu}\,du\\
&=\mu(E)c\int^0_{-\infty}e^{cu}\,du+ c\int^\infty_0\mu(f>u)e^{cu}\,du\\
&=\mu(E)+ c\int^\infty_0\mu(f>u)e^{cu}\,du
\end{align}

Comment: From my thought above, can I get the result? Use $\int_E \phi(f)=-\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\phi(\alpha)d\omega(\alpha)$ ,then separate in two parts.

Comment: @Apple: I just added an alternative method based on a definition of Lebesgue integral develop in Kiev and Loss for example.

Comment: Sorry, why can the last line be deduced from the second to last line?

Comment: Because for any negative number $t$, $\{x\in E: f(x)>t\}=E$ on account that $f\geq0$. Thus $\mu(f>t)=\mu(E)$ on $-\infty<t<0$.